# Is it possible to start over auto-increment each day, with composite keys: date + int? (MSSQL)

Tags: sql-server, composite-primary-key

Lets say i have a small db table with only two fields. (MSSQL) Like this:

```
date (Date)     daily_counter (Int)
-------------------------
2021-07-18      0
2021-07-18      1
2021-07-18      2
2021-07-19      0
```

I want to insert a new fifth row and insert value "2021-07-19" to the date field. And i want to know what the daily_counter is for my new row.

As you perhaps understand by the example, the daily_counter is supposed to auto increase, starting over each day.

So, since there is already a row with that date with the value 0 on the field daily_counter. I want to add 1 to daily_counter for my new row without sending the value 1 to the query.

How can i think when designing this type of table and data. Any hints appreciated. Thanks!

Kr
Gustav

**UPDATE:**

Ok, i think i got something that could work. The only downside would be when deleting and adding new rows, as the new id could be previosly used and deleted and added again.

A side from that i think i got something that i can use.

It might not be pretty now, but it looks like this.

It seems to work also when there is no row for the current day.

```
DECLARE @date DATE
SET @date = '2021-07-22'

DECLARE @daily_counter INT
SET @daily_counter = (SELECT MAX(daily_counter) from mytable where date = @date);
SET @daily_counter = @daily_counter + 1;

IF @daily_counter IS NULL
BEGIN
    SET @daily_counter = 1;
END

INSERT INTO 
mytable 
(date, daily_counter)
OUTPUT @daily_counter

VALUES (@date, @daily_counter)
```

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Use `ROW_NUMBER`?

Comment: i was thinking about a subquery using max(daily_counter) with the refinement of the date field that is being worked

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to make the database do this automatically in the row itself. You must have a single counter across all dates (a [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) would be good for this).

What you can do is use the [`row_number()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to simulate this at the point where you query the data:

```
SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by [date] order by [date])
FROM ...
```

Unfortunately, this will still fail if you need to preserve the original position following deletes, but there's not a good way to do this right now in a database without triggers or application code.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answers guys. I try to follow what you are saying. ROW_NUMBER sounds interesting if it could used to then store the value. Just calculating it every time when querying, might cause problems later on i reckon as you were describing Joel. 

Also max(daily_counter) sounds like it could maybe work.

I think i'll have to try around with these ideas a bit. I'll be back afterwards.

I could also add, that performance/speed is not any big concern in this case. 

Thanks again!